# Generate all combinations which sum to a value without repetitions in R

Tags: r

I have a vector and need to find all combinations where the sum is between a range.

```
set.seed(007)
w <- round(runif(10, 0, 1) * 100)
w
 [1] 99 40 12  7 24 79 34 97 17 46
```

I want a matrix of all combinations (without repetition) of these numbers in "w" whose sum is between 50 and 55
The matrix can contain values 0 and 1 whether the value at that position is to be considered in that solution

> Eg: 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  means 40 and 12 are to be considered

There are many solutions available but they are using repetitions. I couldnt make out how to do this in R.

Any ideas.

Comment: Is a combination always two numbers? Or may it be more?

Comment: @Heroka The combination can be of any size, not necessarily 2.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `combn`, it creates combinations from a vector, without repetitions.

First, we create all combinations:

```
w_comb <- combn(w,2)
```

Then we test wether our combinations fullfill our constraints. We do this (thanks nicola) with colSums.

```
w_comb_tests <- colSums(w_comb) >= 50 & colSums(w_comb) <= 55
```

Finally, we generate a row of 0s and 1s for each selected combination:

```
res <- t(apply(w_comb[,w_comb_tests],2,function(x){
  as.numeric(w %in% x)
}))
```

Comment: Don't use `apply(x,2,sum)`; use `colSums` instead.

Comment: thanks, @nicola! I thought I was being inefficient, but couldn't figure it out. I've changed the answer.